# How to change video default options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently created a video website. At the bottom of the video, there are 3dots when we click on them we can see additional features. But when I click on 3dots from my mobile then this looks very ugly and huge can we make some changes to it?

```css
#video, #vd, #vd1, #vd4, #vd5, #vd6, #vd7, #vd8{
    height: 15em;
    width: 8em;
  }
```

```html
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls>
            <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/448795514.sd.mp4?s=6a4abade3728b02b15506a53807bfbc9cc38f930&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761">
          </video>
```

[image]

Look it is so huge and coming out of video ...
Is there any way to make it small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the controls in CSS/or HTML and Have a custom control design for the video element I have implemented for the pause and play for reference

An example with a removed controls attribute

```js
isPlaying = false;
function playPause(){
  if(!isPlaying) {
document.getElementById('video').play()
document.getElementById('play-pause').innerText = "pause"
isPlaying = !isPlaying
}else{
document.getElementById('video').pause()
document.getElementById('play-pause').innerText = "play"
isPlaying = !isPlaying
}
}
```

```css
#video, #vd, #vd1, #vd4, #vd5, #vd6, #vd7, #vd8{
    height: 15em;
    width: 8em;
  }
  // alternatively you can remove controls in video HTML element below code shows how it can be hidden using css(works only in few browsers)
 video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
display: none !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
```

```html
    <video id="video" width="640" height="480" >
                <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/448795514.sd.mp4?s=6a4abade3728b02b15506a53807bfbc9cc38f930&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761">
     </video>
 <button id="play-pause" onclick="playPause()"> play </button>
```